# Calling a method from template doesn't work (Angular 5)

Tags: angular

There is a capability of Angular that I'm sure pretty much every developer has used sometimes, and which usually works perfect: calling methods from your templates. I've been doing it for months and I haven't had any problem this far.

Until now.

I've got a menu component which loads the menu items dynamically from a DB, and draws them in a visual component. Each endpoint has a routeLink used to traverse through views. This works perfectly and has no trouble on it.

The problem is that now I want to, somehow, leave these routeLinks ("a" elements) selected, so the menu also tells the user in which view he currently is. My approach is to let the "a" element with an orange color if it's selected, with a gray one if it's not. Therefore, I'm going to check the latest category and the final endpoint to have a boolean to determine whether the "a" element text must be orange or gray.

This is the template endpart, embedded inside two ngFors that traverse through categories and subcategories:

```
            <a [routerLink]="thirdLevel.url" 
              [style.color]="checkSelectedUrl(subcategory.key, thirdLevel.key) ? 'orange' : 'gray'"
              class="menu-third-level lvl2" 
              [routerLinkActive]="active-route" 
              [style.marginTop]="isFirst ? '-20px' : '0px'">
        {{ thirdLevel?.title?.toUpperCase() }} </a>
```

As you can see, it calls "checkSelectedUrl", which is a method in the same component that looks like this:

```
checkSelectedUrl(subcategory, endpoint){
    console.log("CHECKING SELECTED URL")
    const parts = window.location.href.split("/")
    const endpointR = parts[parts.length - 1];
    const subcategoryR = parts[parts.length - 2];

    console.log(">>> ", endpointR == endpoint);
    console.log(">>> ", subcategory == subcategoryR);

    return endpointR == endpoint && subcategory == subcategoryR;
}
```

As you can see, it has some consolelogs to check if it works properly. **And they are never shown.** This method never executes, it's like the template is not able to call it for some reason, maybe because of the routeLink, but I have absolutely no idea.

Why can't the template call this method? How can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

edit: this is the whole template:

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="row header">
    <img class="logo" src="../../../assets/menu-header.PNG">
    <div class="row top-right-buttons" *ngIf="menuData">
      <div class="col-md-3 top-menu-item" (click)="topMenuActivity('runs', runsmodal)">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar top-icon"></i>
        <span class="top-menu-text">RUNS</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 top-menu-item" (click)="topMenuActivity('op-service', servicemodal)">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o top-icon"></i>
        <span class="top-menu-text">SERVICE</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 top-menu-item" (click)="topMenuActivity('user', usermodal)">
        <i class="fa fa-user top-icon"></i>
        <span class="top-menu-text">USER</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 top-menu-item" (click)="topMenuActivity('logout', null)">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
        <span class="top-menu-text">LOGOUT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row menu-btn">
    <div class="ext-menu-btn" (click)="openMenu()" *ngIf="menuData">
      <span class="menu-span" [@menuStringAnim]="active">MENU</span>
      <i class="fa fa-bars menu-icon" [@menuIconAnim]="active"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-list" [@menuListAnim]="active" *ngIf="menuData">
  <div class="inner-menu-btn" (click)="openMenu()">
    <span class="menu-span-inner" style="left: 35px">MENU</span>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left menu-close-btn"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-fix " *ngFor="let category of getCategories()">
    <div class="little-menu-bar-toplvl" *ngIf="categoriesNavigator.lvl0 == category.key">
    </div>
    <p class="menu-top-level lvl0" (click)="openCategory(category)">{{ category?.title?.toUpperCase() }} </p>
    <div *ngIf="categoriesNavigator.lvl0 && categoriesNavigator.lvl0 == category.key" class=" second-level-row">
      <br>
      <span class="little-menu-bar-midlvl"></span>
      <div class="row row-fix" *ngFor="let subcategory of getSubcategories(category.key)">
        <p class="menu-second-level lvl1" (click)="openSubcategory(subcategory)">{{ subcategory?.title?.toUpperCase() }} </p>
        <div *ngIf="categoriesNavigator.lvl1 == subcategory.key">
          <br>
          <div class="row row-fix " *ngFor="let thirdLevel of getThirdLevel(category.key, subcategory.key); first as isFirst">
            <div class="little-menu-bar-lowlvl" *ngIf="categoriesNavigator.lvl0 == category.key"></div>

            <a [routerLink]="thirdLevel.url" 
                  [style.color]="checkSelectedUrl(subcategory.key, thirdLevel.key) ? 'orange' : 'gray'"
                  class="menu-third-level lvl2" 
                  [routerLinkActive]="active-route" 
                  [style.marginTop]="isFirst ? '-20px' : '0px'">
            {{ thirdLevel?.title?.toUpperCase() }} </a>

            <!--  <a href="thirdLevel.url" class="menu-third-level lvl2" [style.marginTop]="isFirst ? '-20px' : '0px'">{{ thirdLevel?.title?.toUpperCase() }} </a>
   !-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: routerLinkActive - isn't working properly?  It should add class to an active route and it should be enough to show user where he is. 

"active" class is added to active route?

I guess it should be the first question I would ask but did you declare active variable to which you bind your activeLink? 

Ah and if you don't need to have two way data binding it is enough to do routerLinkActive="class" ( without [] )

Comment: Can you add whole html template.

Comment: @AdrianSawicki Yeah it doesn't work for me, I have no idea why, but it doesn't apply the css class to the element. Gotta add the whole template...

Comment: [routerLinkActive]="active-route" change it to "active" you can't declare active-route variable then on you typescript part add public active = "your class for example 'active-route'" and add .active-route class to your css.

Comment: @AdrianSawicki I declared in my css a class called "active-route", shouldn't it work well like that?

Comment: at the moment it shouldn't if you haven't declared a variable on your typescript part because you at the moment bind it to a variable called active-route not to a class. If you want declare it to a class without binding you shouldn't use [] around routerLinkActive.

Comment: @AdrianSawicki yeah I just tested it that way now, but nothing works. Without the [], pointing directly to class name, it does nothing. I'm starting to think there is a problem with dynamically created URLs (think that this URL is made out of 3 parts, not just 1 simple string) in complex templates. This is a problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to your component decorator.

Comment: @BhanuTejp doesn't work either... there seems to be some kind of Angular limitation here.

Comment: okay you can try to do some kind of workaround with ngClass or ngStyle. You can check if router.url === thirdLevel.url

It would look like [ngStyle]="{'color': router.url === thirdLevel.url ? 'green' : 'red' }"

Ah and if you have routes like /shop/category/books then you would have to get the last part of your url and compare it with your generated url. I don't know how does it exactly looks like in your app but this solution should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if router.url === thirdLevel.url It would look like `[ngStyle]="{'color': router.url === thirdLevel.url ? 'green' : 'red' }"`

Ah and if you have routes like `/shop/category/books` then you would need to get the last part of your URL and compare it with your generated URL. I don't know how does it exactly looks like in your app but this solution should make it work. Still it's just a workaround tho.

It will work with `[ngClass]` too.

If you want to make a fast check of it then add your direct url instead of thirLevel.url for example `[ngStyle]="{'color': router.url === '/signin' ? 'green' : 'red' }"`. Check in console if color was added.

Your `checkSelectedUrl` function is not really a angular way of doing things. You have router module which gives you the needed information and if you have access to active route URL it shouldn't be a problem to toggle class / style.